# Project with Makefile and CMakeLists.txt

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

I have a project which was written in C, not by me. And inside this project there is a folder which has an example written in C++. I should use this example and therefore I wrote a CMakeLists.txt to include all the stuff I need. Everything is working but being new to make, cmake and qtcreator I am having some hard time.

I am not able to understand why :

1. I can import (in QTCreator) the project example which is specified through a CMakeLists.txt while I can't import a project through a makefile.
2. All the includes I have in a .cpp files in qtcreator are marked as: 
   'No Such file or directory' while if I simply do make in the terminal it compiles without any problems. How I can tell qtcreator how to find the libraries and the headers that I included?

EDIT:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project( opencvAprilTagFlea )
find_package( OpenCV REQUIRED )
find_package(VISP REQUIRED)
include_directories("/home/fschiano/Repositories/apriltag2")
include_directories("/home/fschiano/Repositories/apriltag2/common")
find_library(FLYCAPTURE2 flycapture)
add_executable( opencvDemo opencv_demo.cc )

include_directories(${VISP_INCLUDE_DIRS})
message(STATUS "${VISP_INCLUDE_DIRS}")
message(STATUS "${VISP_LIBRARIES}")

# Needed libraries
set (EXTRA_LIBS ${EXTRA_LIBS} apriltag flycapture ${OpenCV_LIBS} ${VISP_LIBRARIES})
target_link_libraries( opencvDemo ${EXTRA_LIBS} )
```

In qtcreator it does not recognize the following includes:

```
#include "visp/vpDisplayGDI.h"
#include <visp/vpDisplayX.h>
#include <visp/vpDot2.h>
#include <visp/vpImageIo.h>
#include <visp/vpPixelMeterConversion.h>

#include <visp/vpPose.h>
#include <visp/vpPoint.h>


#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>

#include "flycapture/FlyCapture2.h"
#include <iostream>

#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"

#include "apriltag.h"
#include "tag36h11.h"
#include "tag36h10.h"
#include "tag36artoolkit.h"
#include "tag25h9.h"
#include "tag25h7.h"
#include "tag16h5.h"
```

Thanks in advance for your help,
Fabrizio.

Comment: 1- Because qtCreator has a parser to CMakeLists.txt and dont have to makefiles. 2- If I understood correctly, you need to edit your CMakeLists.txt with all source and let qtCreator parse this new file

Comment: Can you attach your CMake file?